# unix shell script- what does jot -r 1 1 4 mean? can I replace jot with seq?

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, unix, ubuntu-18.04

I am new to unix and shell script.
I am working on a script to write train and test image file names into two lists:

```
train.list
test.list

COUNT=-1
for folder in $1/*
do
    COUNT=$[$COUNT + 1]
    for imagesFolder in "$folder"/*
    do
        if (( $(jot -r 1 1 $2)  > 1 )); then
            echo "$imagesFolder" $COUNT >> train.list
        else
            echo "$imagesFolder" $COUNT >> test.list
        fi        
    done
done
```

and I get the error:

> /convert_images_to_list.sh: line 31: jot: command not found
>
> ./convert_images_to_list.sh: line 31: ((: > 1 : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "> 1 ")

I tried to change `jot` to `seq` and the error is:

> eq: invalid option -- 'r'
>
> ./convert_images_to_list.sh: line 31: ((: > 1 : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "> 1 ")

I also checked  `'seq --help'` which says `seq [OPTION]... FIRST INCREMENT LAST`.
what does `jot -r 1 1 &2` be replaced with, if I want to use `seq` instead of `jot`.

Thank you very much.

Comment: `$[...]` is obsolete, and has been for decades. Use `$((...))` instead.

Comment: `$((COUNT++))` is easier.

Comment: Depending on your shell, `++` may not be available; POSIX makes it optional (for example, `bash` supports it, but `dash` does not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jot -r 1 1 $2` produces one random number between `1` and `$2`. You can't replace it with `seq`. But you can replace it with `shuf -i1-$2 -n1` which Ubuntu should have.

Comment: Thank you Dan, for the explanation. Yes `shuf -i1-$2 -n1` worked fine. But what do -i1 and -n1 mean here?

Comment: @GayatriTirumalasetty The man pages are your friends. See [man shuf](https://linux.die.net/man/1/shuf) for explanation of options. And also  [man jot](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?jot(1)) might interest your.

Comment: You also have `$RANDOM` in bash for simple RNG.

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't need `jot` or `seq`; you are just trying to generate a random integer between 1 and `$2`. As long as `$2` isn't too large and you aren't terribly concerned about using a uniform distribution, you can replace it with

```
# $RANDOM yields a value between 0 and 32767
# Thus, $RANDOM % $2 yields a value between 0 and $2 - 1
if (( $RANDOM % $2 > 0 )); then
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the above answer, I could solve this problem of selecting a portion of image folders into two lists or categories by replacing `jot -r 1 1 &2` with a `for` loop to select from a sequence of numbers.

```
for imagesFolder in "$folder"/*
    do
        for t in $(seq 1 1 $2)
        do 
            if (( t  > 1 )); then
                echo "in train"
                echo "$imagesFolder" $COUNT >> train.list
            else
                echo "in test"
                echo "$imagesFolder" $COUNT >> test.list
            fi 
        done       
    done
```